# Too many classes in groovy CallSiteClassLoader

Tags: groovy

In our application we embed groovy 1.8.9 jar and invoke a groovy script from Java code at run time. The groovy scripts are not changing in each call and can be considered fixed logic.
When we run the application for a long time we see too many classes in org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/callsite/CallSiteClassLoader
in fact for each call, we see a class being generated. This leads to GC pressure and unpleasant side effects.

since our groovy scripts are unchanged from call to call, is there a way to reuse the callsite classes generated once.

Comment: Can you spike test it with a more recent version of Groovy and see if you see the same issue?  If so, can you post a simple example piece of code that shows this issue?

Comment: is there a way to avoid the creation of callsite classes, or reuse the same class created earlier

Comment: I don't know, I can't guess your code